# use lastPage instead of page value if its greater than lastPage value laravel pagination

Tags: jquery, laravel-4, pagination

Good day,

I am currently working on my ajax pagination and its working fine except for 1 thing.

If the `page` variable is greater then `lastPage` there will be no data displayed.

here is my controller

```
$transactions = DB::table('x_general_transactions')
    ->whereBetween('x_general_transactions.date_at', array($startDate,$endDate))
    ->paginate($per_page);
```

because when I try to set `page=100` when the last page is actually only `10` it wont display anything then. Is there a way that If I set `page=100` it will check for the `lastPage` value then if `lastPage` is greater `page=lastPage` ?

```
if ($transactions->getLastPage() < $page) {
            $page = $transactions->getLastPage();
    }
```

I have no I idea where to put the code above. Thanks/

Answer (score 1):

I see two solutions. In shortcut:

Get count of all records in database, and split it by records_per_page number, and create that amount of pagination buttons. It is very simple, and common solution.

If You want to go hard, becouse of some reason, create class let's say PaginationValidator, and register custom rule, like [here](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/validation#custom-validation-rules)

Then ,  if pagination is over one or more models? If more -> use handler of Jeffrey Way, if not just put this code in before filter in controller constructor `

```
public function __construct()
{

    $this->beforeFilter('PaginationValidator@pagination', array('only' =>
                        array('fooAction', 'barAction')));
}
```

In PaginationValidator get query, how many records are in dataBase, and compare it with requested number. Nice and smooth. Have a nice day!